# How to associate records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

I have two tables: author table and article table. How can I associate the records modified in the article table with the author table

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :article
  has_paper_trail
end

class Article < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [belongs_to](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association) on Article. This will save the author_id on the Article object.

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
end
```